# JQuery changing SelectedValue in databound ASP.NET DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net

I have a `ASP.NET` form (`c#`, `MySQL` backend) that shows among others three `DropDownList` widgets

```
<asp:FormView
    ID="_fvNoleggio"
    runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="id"
    DataSourceID="_sdsNoleggio"
    DefaultMode="Edit" >
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Table runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label 
                            AssociatedControlID="_ddlAssicurazioneCedente"
                            ID="_lblAssicurazioneCedente" 
                            runat="server" 
                            Text="Assicurazione cedente" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList 
                            ID="_ddlAssicurazioneCedente"
                            ClientIDMode="Static"
                            runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="_sdsAssicurazione"
                            onchange="javascript: CheckAssicurazione(this);"
                            DataTextField="nome" 
                            DataValueField="id"
                            AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                       SelectedValue='<%#Eval("id_assicurazione_cedente")%>' >
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Nessuna" Value="" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label
                          AssociatedControlID="_ddlAssicurazioneControparte"
                            ID="_lblAssicurazioneControparte" 
                            runat="server" 
                            Text="Assicurazione cedente" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList 
                             ID="_ddlAssicurazioneControparte"
                             ClientIDMode="Static"
                             runat="server" 
                             DataSourceID="_sdsAssicurazione"
                             onchange="javascript:CheckAssicurazione(this);"
                             DataTextField="nome" 
                             DataValueField="id"
                             AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                   SelectedValue='<%#Eval("id_assicurazione_controparte")%>' >
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Nessuna" Value="" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label 
                            AssociatedControlID="_ddlAssicurazionePagante"
                            ID="_lblAssicurazionePagante" 
                            runat="server" 
                            Text="Assicurazione cedente" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList 
                            ID="_ddlAssicurazionePagante"
                            ClientIDMode="Static"
                            runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="_sdsAssicurazione"
                            onchange="javascript: CheckAssicurazione(this);"
                            DataTextField="nome" 
                            DataValueField="id"
                            AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                       SelectedValue='<%#Eval("id_assicurazione_pagante")%>' >
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Nessuna." Value="" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>&nbsp;</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

They all are fed trough a single `SQLDataSource` element while `SelectedValue` properties are bound to matching field of the master fieldset (feeding the including `FormView`):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="_sdsAssicurazione" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mydb %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mydb.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand=" SELECT 
                       * 
                    FROM 
                       assicurazioni;">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="_sdsNoleggio" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mydb %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mydb.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand=" SELECT 
                       * 
                    FROM 
                       noleggio_veicoli;">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I need to check selected values in the first two `DDL` (plus another external value) to set the third `DDL` selected value. This's the .js code I'm using:

```
function CheckAssicurazione(widget) {
    if (widget == null)
        return;

    CheckAssicurazionePagante();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Service/WSDataService.asmx/CheckAssicurazione",
        data: "{'id':'" + widget.value + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == null)
                return;

            if (data.d == null)
                return;

            if (data.d == "True")
                alert("Warning!")
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}

function CheckAssicurazionePagante()
{
    // _tipo_indennizzio is a global value that is set in another section of code and is not null (I debugged it)

    if (_tipo_indennizzo == null)
        return;

    var _assicurazione_controparte = $('#_ddlAssicurazioneControparte option:selected').val();
    var _assicurazione_cedente = $('#_ddlAssicurazioneCedente option:selected').val();
    var _assicurazione_pagante = null;

    if (_tipo_indennizzo == "DIRETTO")
        _assicurazione_pagante = _assicurazione_cedente;
    else if (_tipo_indennizzo == "TRADIZIONALE")
        _assicurazione_pagante = _assicurazione_controparte;
    else
        return;

    var _assicurazione_pagante_selezionata = $('select#_ddlAssicurazionePagante option:selected').val();

    if (isBlank(_assicurazione_pagante_selezionata) || (_assicurazione_pagante_selezionata != _assicurazione_pagante))
    {
        var _result = confirm("warning ?");

        // If the user answer 'yes' to the confirm dialog the third DDL should be set to the 'correct' value

        if (_result == true) {
            $('#_ddlAssicurazionePagante option:selected').val(_assicurazione_pagante);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work... the value seems to be set correctly (no exception is thrown) but as a matter of fact the DDL rendered in the web page is not updated.

Where I'm wrong? BTW I'm working with `jquery 2.1.3` and `jquery-ui 1.11.2`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.js"></script>
```

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you get and set the value of the selected item of each DropDownList. You should get and set the value of the DropDownList itself:

```
var _assicurazione_controparte = $('#_ddlAssicurazioneControparte').val();
var _assicurazione_cedente = $('#_ddlAssicurazioneCedente').val();

...

$('#_ddlAssicurazionePagante').val(_assicurazione_pagante);
```